# Anchor navigation - target div should be always on the container top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement next behavior:
When I click to link with anchor - target div should be reposition top his container top (container's height should be increased if needed).
Here is a "html/css - draft" - http://jsfiddle.net/k2dGD/

Please help me with javascript.

Html:

```
 <div class="triggers">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
    <a href="#four">Four</a>
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
</div>

    <div class="blocks">
    <div id="one" class="block">
        BLOCK ONE --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem exercitationem dolores officiis omnis nostrum molestiae quo laboriosam iure placeat velit sit porro illum eius repellendus suscipit nemo dignissimos! Delectus atque.
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="block">
        BLOCK TWO --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem exercitationem dolores officiis omnis nostrum molestiae quo laboriosam iure placeat velit sit porro illum eius repellendus suscipit nemo dignissimos! Delectus atque.
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="block">
        BLOCK THREE --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem exercitationem dolores officiis omnis nostrum molestiae quo laboriosam iure placeat velit sit porro illum eius repellendus suscipit nemo dignissimos! Delectus atque.
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="block">
        BLOCK FOUR --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem exercitationem dolores officiis omnis nostrum molestiae quo laboriosam iure placeat velit sit porro illum eius repellendus suscipit nemo dignissimos! Delectus atque.
    </div>
    <div id="five" class="block">
        BLOCK FIVE --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem exercitationem dolores officiis omnis nostrum molestiae quo laboriosam iure placeat velit sit porro illum eius repellendus suscipit nemo dignissimos! Delectus atque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show some attempt at the JavaScript and explain where exactly you have having problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should show some effort in resolving your issue otherwise it's like "Hey you! Do it for me!" Regardless I'll try to help you cause it's your first post. Take care anyway in the future not to do the same mistake or really go find a freelancer if you don't understand how code it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('.triggers a').click(function(){
        var $item = $( $(this).attr('href') );
        $(this).closest('div').next('.blocks').prepend( $item );
    });

});
```